# Passing value from one html template to another in Django

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am making a web project using Django and relatively new to Django.
I am stuck at the following part:
I want to get user input from one html search box and display it on another html page.

This is my first page:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #title{margin-top:150px;font-size:40px; font-family:"roboto"; text-align:center; color:grey}
        #info_text{margin-top:10px;font-size:15px; font-family:"roboto"; text-align:center; color:grey}
        #search_bar{height:40px;margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:9px;width:50%; margin-left: 24%}
        #search_button{height:50px;margin-top:20px;width:20%;margin-left: 40%;background-color:grey; font-size:40px; font-family:"roboto"; text-align:center; color: white}
    </style>
</head>
<body id="body">
    <div>
        <h1 id="title">Enter Value</h1>
        <form action="result" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input id="search_bar" type="text" name="search_box" onfocus="this.value=''">
            <input type="submit" value="Search" id="search_button">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my view.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'templates/home.html')

def result(request):
    raw_details = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        raw_deatils = request.POST.get('search_box', None)
    print(raw_details)
    return render(request, 'templates/result.html', raw_details)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by saving data to django `sessions`.

```
 <form action="{% url 'result' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input id="search_box" type="text" name="search_box" onfocus="this.value=''">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" id="search_button">
 </form>
```

views:

```
def result(request):
    
    if 'search_box' in request.POST:
        request.session['search_data'] = request.POST['search_box']

    return render(request, 'templates/result.html')
```

Now the inputted data will be saved in `request.session['search_data']`

And you can access it in other views like:

```
def exampleView(request):
    
    if 'search_data' in request.session:
        //...do something...//

    return render(request, 'exampleApp/exampleView.html')
```

Comment: Thanks but when I change the from action method I got and error stating this "NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for 'result' not found. 'result' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

Comment: What is `result` called in your `urls.py`?

Comment: The actual problem was with my result.html file. I didn't specified anything to accept value from the home page. Now I am able to pass value. Thanks for all the help.